# Does Einstein's original derivation of $E=mc^2$ exist and what is it?

Tags: physics

I read an article published by *Scientific American* stating that Einstein did not prove the equation within the context of Special Relativity but I am skeptical. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on the history of this famous equation.

Comment: Perhaps look for his handwritten 1912 manuscript on the theory of special relativity?

Comment: See, for example, http://www.aparchive.com/metadata/youtube/50ab0521030bb4671c21f5793fca8d86

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Einstein's mass-energy relation usually written as $E=mc^2$, and not $\Delta E=\Delta m c^2$?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/why-is-einsteins-mass-energy-relation-usually-written-as-e-mc2-and-not-de)

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful links and suggestions. Joel and Conifold you have both been very helpful. I will read through the material. There may have been some confusion on my part concerning the original question. I will get back after finishing reading.